# Animating -webkit-filter with jQuery

Tags: css

Okay, so I have a filter on a div, that's making the background image of that div greyscale by default using these css properties.

I understand my onblur and onfocus works and how to use them along with animate() using jQuery.

Such as this, which works and makes sense to me:

```
$('div.cell').hover(function() {
    $('div.cell').animate({

        border: 'none',
        height: '100px',
    }, 2000, function() {

    // Animation complete.

    });
});
```

Now I am having a problem with the syntax of animating certain css3 properties.

Instead of animating `border: none` and `height: 100px` but how do I get to animate these two properties???

```
filter: none;
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
```

What I have now is this:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').animate({
    filter: 'none'
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

But I am getting MAJOR syntax errors while trying to animate `-webkit-filter` from `grayscale(1);` to `grayscale(0);`

Thanks guys! Let me know if there's anything else you need.

---

So here's what I have now....

```
$(function() {
    $("div.cell").focus(function(){
        alert('WHOA');
        $("div.cell").attr('grayNow');
    });
});​
```

and its not working still...

along with some css

```
.grayNow {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0); 
    filter: none;  
}​
```

I'm not even getting the alert! :(

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure why you would use jQuery animate to do this, as if you use transitions then these animations are hardware accelerated – jQuery animate should only be used as a last resort, or in situations where support is required in old browsers.

Anyway:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ej8s3/

In short, add a transition, make a class with the new properties, toggle it on and off using some JS. I've used jQuery, but it's trivial to do this without.

Comment: grayscale(1) = full gray, not 0. Why not put up a jsfiddle with your code, I'll have a look and see what's wrong.

Comment: Also, cells don't have a focus event, I'd guess that click might be more appropriate, or hover.

Comment: Wasn't aware of the hardware acceleration not being available in JQuery. Thanks for passing on the information.